# Confusion table with percentage instead of counts in R

Tags: r, statistics

I know how to make a table in R with the TABLE function: table(sunshine_pred, sunshine)

```
               sunshine?
               Yes    No
  pred_yes:     100    400
  pred_no:      400    100
```

However, is there a way to automatically create this output in a percentage instead of counts?  Is there some syntax I am missing?

A small bonus would be if there was also percentages of the correctly predicted, incorrectly predicted, and percentages of each column/row...But the percentage counts in each cell is most needed.

```
 10%     40%
 40%     10%
```

Comment: You can give a try to `prop.table` and read the description of this function.

Comment: `round(prop.table(table(x,y))*100)` if you want the whole numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the table by its sum.

As so:

```
n <- 20

x <- rnorm(n, sd=1.5)
x <- cut(x, breaks=(-5:5))
y <- sample( c('a', 'b', 'c'), n, replace=T)

t <- table(x,y)

print(t)

# print fraction
print(t/sum(t))
```

to print a percentage, multiple by 100